# Using tinymce inline div InnerHtml in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, innerhtml, tinymce-4

I'm trying to set up a tinymce inline edit in a .net page but I'm struggeling to pick up the edited text from the div's InnerHtml.

```
<script src="../Scripts/Tiny4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "div.edit",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
            ["advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker"],
            ["searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking"],
            ["save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste"]
        ],
        add_unload_trigger: false,
        schema: "html5",
        inline: true,
        toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image     | print preview media",
        statusbar: false
    });


</script> 

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div runat="server" ID="editdiv" class="edit">Original text</div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    </div>
    </form>
```

ASP Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/tiny.mdb"));
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [tinytest] SET [divtext] = @divtext WHERE ID = 34", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divtext", editdiv.InnerHtml);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

The tinymce editor kicks in as expected but when I try to send the InnerHtml to the code behind I just get the original text not the edited version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `div` isn't a very good place to store values in a web form.

If the framework is getting the value for `editdiv.InnerHtml` from anywhere it's probably from the view state.  At the very least, it's certainly not from the client-side HTML.  This is because when the page posts back to the server it's still, regardless of what WebForms is trying to make you think, a normal HTML form post.  Which means its values are coming from `form` elements and *only* from `form` elements.  HTML page content isn't posted to the server.  View state is, because it's a base-64 encoded string stuffed into an `input type="hidden"` on the page.

What you *can* do is create you're own hidden input:

```
<asp:Hidden runat="server" id="editdivcontents" />
```

Then in your client-side code you would update the value of the resulting `input type="hidden"` when you change the content of that `div`.  That value would then be posted back to the server and can be accessed:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@divtext", editdivcontents.Text);
```

I'm not *entirely* sure how to update the hidden input element when the `div` changes, since I'm not familiar with TinyMCE.  (Though I suppose it could be done manually outside of that tool by responding to an event in the DOM.)  But ultimately that's what you're going to need to do, since only form element values and not DOM content is what gets posted to the server.

Comment: Thanks @David that makes sense. I've used a jquery onchange to update the hidden input. 
`$('.edit').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    $('input[id="editdivcontents"]').val($('.edit').html());
});`